# Finding basis of cohomology of a symplectic manifold by using Symplectic Minimal Model Program

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, cohomology, symplectic-topology, minimal-model-program, floer-homology

My question is about Floer theory via symplectic surgery of Minimal Model program for finding basis of cohomology.

**Motivation**: Perelman for solving Thurston's Geometrization Conjecture used some sort of Surgery and later Gang Tian extended [Thurston's Geometrization Conjecture for symplectic manifolds](https://academic.oup.com/nsr/article/2615238/New-Geometric-Flows) by using Symplectic Minimal Model Program.

Let $X$ be a smooth compact symplectic manifold and $H(X,\mathbb Q)$ be its cohomology and there are two standard ways to find the basis of cohomology.

**I**. We can use Morse theory. Let $f:X\to \mathbb R$ be a Morse function then there is a Morse complex $CM(X)=\mathbb Z[Crit(f)]$ and the boundary operator $\partial$ counts isolated gradient trajectories and we can compute the cohomology and we can get the basis of cohomology

**II.** The second strategy to compute the basis of $H(X,\mathbb Q)$ is to use Symplectic Minimal Model Program.

Let $(X,\omega)$ be a symplectic manifold

The naive idea is to try to vary $\omega$ in the direction of negative first Chern class $-c_1(X)$ and whenever $\omega$ becomes degenerate, we do use some sort of surgery as the symplectic version of Minimal Model Program which is flips or blow-downs.

If we start up with $X$ and inside $X$ we find locus which is non-degenerate and this turns out to be projective bundle

$$X\supset\mathbb P(N)\to Z\to \mathbb P(N')\subset X'$$
which $Z$ called center and $X'$ is flips. The good example is $X=\text{blow up}^2(S^2\times S^2)$. In this case $\dim H(X)=6$

Now the idea of varying symplectic form in direction of negative first Chern class is as same as finding Kahler cone of solutions of Kahler-Ricci flow. like $[\omega]-tc_1(X)$. In fact the idea of second strategy work when $c_1(X)<0$ or $Kod(X)=dim X$. So in my analytical point of view when we are facing with $0<Kod(X)<dim X$, then the cone of solutions of Ricci flow changes and we need to use first Chern class of relative canonical bundle along Iitaka fibration $c_1(K_{X/X_{can}})$ where $X_{can}$ is canonical model of $X$. So it is unlikely for such cases varying symplectic form in negative direction of first Chern class work!.
Is there any example such that confirm the paper of [François Charest, Chris T. Woodward, Floer theory and flips](https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.01573) for finding basis of cohomology of $X$
when $0<kod(X)<dimX$(take X is Kahler manifold)

Comment: Dear Dr. Jolany, what you describe appears to be quite complicated a procedure. Is the point using of this procedure that the representatives for cohomology classes you construct have some nice geometric properties?

Comment: See paper of Grisha Perelman http://www.mathnet.ru/links/69a94441404d5229f1d48273ad313d51/aa374.pdf and https://www.slideshare.net/HassanJolany/canonical-metric-on-khler-manifolds , then you get the main point . (it may take 3-6 years but good luck! )